# Error in executing AsyncTask class in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I have an android `AsyncTask` class from where am trying to access an SQLite database. Everything is working OK, but I'am having errors and I don't know how to solve them.

Here is my class:

```
protected HomeActivity doInBackground(HomeActivity... params) {
        Cursor cursor = null;

        // dbhandler.addShares(update_list());
        cursor = dbhandler.getShares();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String name, price, cash_change, percentage_change;
            name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME));
            price = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE));
            cash_change = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_CASH_CHANGE));
            percentage_change = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_PERCENTAGE_CHANGE));

            SharePrices sharePrices = new SharePrices();
            sharePrices.setName(name);
            sharePrices.setPrice(price);
            sharePrices.setPercentageChange(percentage_change);
            sharePrices.setCashChange(cash_change);

            shares.add(sharePrices);
        }

        if (null != cursor) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

And the stack trace:

```
09-26 17:15:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-26 17:15:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-26 17:15:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
09-26 17:15:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-26 17:15:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
09-26 17:15:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
09-26 17:15:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-26 17:15:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
09-26 17:15:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
09-26 17:15:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-26 17:15:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(2069): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 17:15:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at com.intelligent.stocktrader.HomeActivity$getShares.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:106)
09-26 17:15:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at com.intelligent.stocktrader.HomeActivity$getShares.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:1)
09-26 17:15:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
09-26 17:15:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-26 17:15:54.590: E/AndroidRuntime(2069):     ... 4 more
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069): Activity com.intelligent.stocktrader.HomeActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41190a88 that was originally added here
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.intelligent.stocktrader.HomeActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41190a88 that was originally added here
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:343)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:245)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at com.intelligent.stocktrader.HomeActivity$getShares.onPreExecute(HomeActivity.java:81)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at com.intelligent.stocktrader.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:71)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-26 17:15:55.331: E/WindowManager(2069):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Which one is line 106 in HomeActivity? There is a NullPointerException

Comment: have you mentioned startManagingCursor() anywhere in the code?

Comment: Thanks man,i have spotted it.guess i was too exhausted was going through it but not noticing.

Comment: @NightCrawler: mark that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You must use either startManagingCursor()/cursor.close()